# Why do `/_nuxt/static/... ` page paths appear on Google Analytics? (Nuxt.js + GA4 + vue-gtag)

Tags: vue.js, google-analytics, nuxt.js

I'm using Google Analytics (GA4) with a Nuxt.js static site hosted on Netlify. The GA tracking is done with [vue-gtag](https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-gtag).

It has been working fine for a couple months, but the other day, I noticed an unusually high influx of New User and Session traffic specifically to some of my page paths prefixed with `/_nuxt/static/XXXXXXXXXX/...` (X denotes some digits). They have "(not set)" Locations, zero Screen Views and zero Average Engagement Times, unlike other legitimate page paths and traffic stats I'm seeing, so I am assuming that they are bots of some sort... but I have no idea where from. **Why would particular pages in the static folder get hit like that? And how could they be exposed in the first place?**

I'm quite new to all this so I tried researching more about Nuxt static sites, the static folder, and static site generators like Netlify... but I'm not finding anything specifically about these hits showing up on Google Analytics.

I'd appreciate if anyone would be kind enough to explain all this to me!

---

EDIT - re: kissu's comment on how I've enabled `vue-gtag`:

I made a Nuxt plugin I've called `googleAnalytics.js` with the following code:

```html
import Vue from "vue";
import VueGtag from "vue-gtag";

export default ({ app }) => {
  // get browser's hostname to check for localhost
  let host = window.location.hostname;

  // only run the Google Analytics code thru vue-gtag if hostname is not localhost
  if (host != "localhost") {
    Vue.use(
      VueGtag,
      {
        config: { id: "G-XXXXXXXXXX" },
        appName: "SomeName",
        pageTrackerScreenviewEnabled: true
      },
      // pass application router to vue-gtag so that it associates tracking information with the specific page in view
      // code from: https://www.carlcassar.com/articles/add-google-analytics-to-a-nuxt-js-app/
      app.router
    );
  }
};
```

And then in my `nuxt.config.js` I set it to client-only:

```html
  plugins: [
    {
      src: "./plugins/googleAnalytics.js",
      mode: "client"
    },
```

That's all I've done with respect to the GA tracking. Are there are any other config options I should be using?

I'm on Nuxt v2.15.3 and vue-gtag v1.14.0.

Comment: Maybe you used it on dev by error? How is your `vue-gtag` enabled on production?

Comment: Hm, that's a good point, thanks for bringing it up. I must admit, I'm not sure about how to disable/enable `vue-gtag` differently from dev vs. production. I've edited my question details above to include the code on how I enabled it -- hope it's relevant in answering your question. What I do know is that I hadn't been working on the site at all for +/-1 week around the time the traffic hit, so I'm not sure if it's anything to do with development... though I may be misunderstanding your point. Perhaps something was triggered on the Netlify side of things?

Comment: You can have a conditional on the `enabled` key as shown here: https://matteo-gabriele.gitbook.io/vue-gtag/opt-in-out Checking a value in your `.env` may be a good way of enabling/disabling it IMO.

Comment: Thank you for this tip -- I'll look more into using environment variables as I'm new to it, but will definitely give this a try!